# Shuffling several groups of banners

Tags: javascript, shuffle

I'm using this to rotate some banners, but the problem is that if I have more than 3 ou 4 `vars` (group of banners), the `document.getElementById` stops working.

Any ideas why? Or perhaps is there a better way of doing it?

```
var banner = [
["destination1.com", "https://via.placeholder.com/468x60?text=468x60+Full", "alt Title 1", "event label 1"],
["destination2.com", "https://via.placeholder.com/728x90?text=728x90+Leaderboard", "alt Title 2", "event label 2"]
];

function shuffle(a) {
    var j, x, i;
    for (i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        x = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = x;
    }
    return a;
}

shuffle(banner);
document.getElementById('vidmob').innerHTML = '<a href="'+banner[0][0]+'" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="'+bannervideosmob[0][1]+'" style="z-index:5;border:none" alt="'+banner[0][2]+'" onClick="gtag(\'event\', \'Click\', {\'event_category\': \'ads\',\'event_label\': \'mob-'+banner[0][3]+'\'});" /></a>';
```

[source](https://owlcation.com/stem/JavaScript-Banner-Rotator)

Example of implementation not working with 3 or more banners:

```
var banner = [
["destination1.com", "https://via.placeholder.com/468x60?text=468x60+Full", "alt Title 1", "event label 1"],
["destination2.com", "https://via.placeholder.com/728x90?text=728x90+Leaderboard", "alt Title 2", "event label 2"]
];
var banner1 = [
["destination3.com", "https://via.placeholder.com/300x250?text=300x250+MPU", "alt Title 3", "event label 3"],
["destination4.com", "https://via.placeholder.com/120x600?text=120x600+Skyscraper", "alt Title 4", "event label 4"]
];
var banner2 = [
["destination5.com", "https://via.placeholder.com/160x600?text=160x600+Wide+Skyscaper", "alt Title 5", "event label 5"],
["destination6.com", "https://via.placeholder.com/300x600?text=300x600+Half+Page+Ad", "alt Title 6", "event label 6"]
];
var banner3 = [
["destination7.com", "https://via.placeholder.com/125x125?text=125x125+Square+Button", "alt Title 7", "event label 7"],
["destination8.com", "https://via.placeholder.com/234x60?text=234x60+Half+Banner", "alt Title 8", "event label 8"]
];


function shuffle(a) {
    var j, x, i;
    for (i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        x = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = x;
    }
    return a;
}

shuffle(banner);
document.getElementById('divid1').innerHTML = '<a href="'+banner[0][0]+'" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="'+banner[0][1]+'" style="z-index:5;border:none" alt="'+banner[0][2]+'" onClick="gtag(\'event\', \'Click\', {\'event_category\': \'ads\',\'event_label\': \'mob-'+banner[0][3]+'\'});" /></a>';

shuffle(banner1);
document.getElementById('divid2').innerHTML = '<a href="'+banner1[0][0]+'" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="'+banner1[0][1]+'" style="z-index:5;border:none" alt="'+banner1[0][2]+'" onClick="gtag(\'event\', \'Click\', {\'event_category\': \'ads\',\'event_label\': \'mob-'+banner1[0][3]+'\'});" /></a>';

shuffle(banner2);
document.getElementById('divid3').innerHTML = '<a href="'+banner2[0][0]+'" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="'+banner2[0][1]+'" style="z-index:5;border:none" alt="'+banner2[0][2]+'" onClick="gtag(\'event\', \'Click\', {\'event_category\': \'ads\',\'event_label\': \'mob-'+banner2[0][3]+'\'});" /></a>';

shuffle(banner3);
document.getElementById('divid4').innerHTML = '<a href="'+banner3[0][0]+'" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="'+banner3[0][1]+'" style="z-index:5;border:none" alt="'+banner3[0][2]+'" onClick="gtag(\'event\', \'Click\', {\'event_category\': \'ads\',\'event_label\': \'mob-'+banner3[0][3]+'\'});" /></a>';
```

This is how I call them:

```
<div class="mob" id="banner"></div>
<div class="mob" id="banner1"></div>
<div class="mob" id="banner2"></div>
<div class="mob" id="banner3"></div>
<div class="mob" id="banner4"></div>
```

Comment: Show your HTML code with those "dividX".

Comment: @MajdJamal Just updated te question, thanks!

Comment: You don't seem to have a div with id-name "divid4".

Comment: @MajdJamal question edited... but that is not the problem.